# Set container to fixed height and scrollable

Tags: html, css

I've the following:

```
<section class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I set `<section>` to a fixed height so that I will need to scroll to see more rows?

Comment: Please add the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more wrap around `.table`. Apply css `overflow-y` and `height` on parent.

```css
.table-holder {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section class="table-holder">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 1</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The other answers work only for ordinary circumstances, but not for tables. Yours however works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you need to apply `overflow-x` and `height` to `<section>` class.

`overflow-x` property specifies what to do with the top/bottom edges of the content - if it overflows the element's content area.

```css
.table {
      height: 100px; /* For fixed height */
      width: 100px;
      overflow-y: scroll; /* For scrolling */
}
```

```html
<section class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

More **helpful information** about `overflow` property:

- [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)
- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)
- [Overflow-y](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)
- [Live examples with overflow-y](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow-y&preval=scroll)

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your css

```
section.table {
    height: 55px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

if you want only vertical scroll then use `overflow-y:scroll;` or for horizontal `overflow-x:scroll;`